# Implementing smooth motion in 2d space in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to implement smooth motion that accelerates up to max speed and then decelerates slowly if no keys are pressed, similar to the motion of the space ship in asteroid. Here is my current code for the movement:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

GRAY = pygame.Color('gray12')

display_width, display_height = display.get_size()

x = display_width * 0.45
y = display_height * 0.8

x_change = 0
y_change = 0
accel_x = 0
accel_y = 0
max_speed = 6

sign = lambda a: (a > 0) - (a < 0)

crashed = False
while not crashed:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Set the acceleration value.
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print('left')
                accel_x = -.2
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print('right')
                accel_x = .2
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                print('down')
                accel_y = .2
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print('up')
                accel_y = -.2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                print('key up')
                accel_x = 0
                accel_y = 0

    x_change += accel_x  # Accelerate.
    y_change += accel_y

    if abs(x_change) >= max_speed:  # If max_speed is exceeded.
        # Normalize the x_change and multiply it with the max_speed.
        x_change = sign(x_change) * max_speed

    if abs(y_change) >= max_speed:  # If max_speed is exceeded.
        # Normalize the y_change and multiply it with the max_speed.
        y_change = sign(y_change) * max_speed

    # Decelerate if no key is pressed.
    if accel_x == 0:
        x_change *= 0.98

    if accel_y == 0:
        y_change *= 0.98

    x += x_change  # Move the object.
    y += y_change

    display.fill(GRAY)
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 120, 250), (x, y, 20, 40))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

When pressing the arrow keys individually the motion works perfectly, however if pressing 2 keys in rapid succession, the second key is registered but there is no motion from the object. I've tried making a list of keys using `pygame.key.get_pressed()` and comparing the current motion with the key pressed in the list, however this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: By "pressing 2 keys in rapid succession" do you mean two different keys or the same one twice in a row?

Comment: pressing 2 different keys, ie changing direction quickly from left to right

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: It happens through instant key switching. If the game is being played at high speeds the player will press the second key a split second before, or just as the first key is being released. When implementing it in the game it happens almost every time I try to move quickly.

Comment: Yes, I that's what I thought (and tried) At this point I can only speculate, but perhaps you could have a "game state" variable that gets changed when ever any of the arrow key are pressed and released, which would allow it "track" what it's doing — i.e. something more explicit that whether `accel_x` or `accel_y` are `== 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major issue in your code is, that when you press and <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, then press and hold <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> and finally release <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, the resulting states of `accel_x` and `accel_y` are both 0, because the last event that happend was `pygame.KEYUP`.

I recommend to evaluate the states of [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) rather than to use the key events:

- If <kbd>UP</kbd> is pressed and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> is not pressed, the increment `y_change` up to its maximum (`y_change = max(y_change-0.2, -max_speed)`).
- If <kbd>UP</kbd> is not pressed and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> is pressed, the decrement `y_change` down to its minimum (`y_change = min(y_change+0.2, max_speed)`).
- If both keys are pressed simultaneously or no one of them is pressed, then decrease the speed (`y_change *= 0.98`).

Apply the same principle to `x_change`, when the keys <kbd>LEFT</kbd> and/or <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> are pressed:

[image]

```py
crashed = False
while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # handle left and right movement
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and not keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x_change = max(x_change-0.2, -max_speed)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x_change = min(x_change+0.2, max_speed)
    else:
        x_change *= 0.98

    # handle up and down movement
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and not keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y_change = max(y_change-0.2, -max_speed)
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and not keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y_change = min(y_change+0.2, max_speed)
    else:
        y_change *= 0.98

    x += x_change  # Move the object.
    y += y_change

    display.fill(GRAY)
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 120, 250), (x, y, 20, 40))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```